# Cross account ECR access for kubernetes nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, kubelet, amazon-ecr

I have to a topology that involves two or more AWS accounts:

1. **My production account**, in which I publish application images to ECR, and additional files to S3 bucket
2. One or more **cusotmer accounts**, which has an EKS cluster that pulls images and files from the ECR and S3 buckets respectively

It don't want to publicly expose my resources for obvious reasons, thus I need to enable access only for specific customers (account numbers)

I want to manage my customers in a single place, thus I want to enable all those resources to a specific role that I'll allow my customers to assume (A list AWS account numbers).

The problem I encounter is in the kubelet area, I can't find a way to tell my EKS workers/kubelets to assume this role. Is it possible? If not, what other alternative I have if I want to manage my customer's in a single place?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. AWS is very much screwed this up, looks like there are no options to share and entire ECR private registry with  another account, or atleast namespace, Managing the permission on individual repository level is very difficult with 100s of repositories..

Answer (score 0):

You can add a repository policy to your ECR repo in the production account and allow your customer accounts to pull the Image. You can refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-account-access-ecr/) document for step by step instructions to achieve the same.

Comment: I have 2 problem with that approach: 1. If I can't set one policy for multiple repositories (which I use per app image). 2. I'll also need to set a policy for the S3 buckets

Comment: This approach is not manageable if you have 100s of ecr repos.